# netstandard 2.0 is not compatible with netstandard 2.0

Tags: c#, nuget, .net-standard-2.0

I'm trying to create a NuGet package from my project, which is targeting .net standard 2.0. When I add this package as a reference from NuGet package manager I get the following errors

```
Package packageName is not compatible with netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0). Package packageName supports: netstandart20 (netstandart2.0,Version=v0.0)    
Package packageName is not compatible with net461 (.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1). Package packageName supports: netstandart20 (netstandart2.0,Version=v0.0)
```

Also I am able to add this project as a reference to the project, where NuGet fails. How can I fix this?

Comment: Probably by making sure you target `netstandard`, not `netstandart`.

Comment: (Or rather, the *package* should support netstandard20 instead of netstandart20. Hopefully it's a package you're able to change...)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Does your TargetFramework look like this?

```
<TargetFramework>netstandart20</TargetFramework>
```

If so, the solution is probably just to fix the typo and make it look like this (standar**d**, not standar**t**):

```
<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
```

Comment: If this is indeed the issue, voting to close as "due to a typo" is more appropriate than providing an answer that fixes the typo, as such questions are unlikely to help future readers.